# React,Redux drag selection

Tags: reactjs, redux, drag-and-drop

everyone. How can I implement such thing([jQUery Selectable](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/)) in my react&redux app? I need to know what items were selected and change my store respectively. I have read about D&D but have no idea, how to do it in react&redux way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following library , i've used it couple of times, it served the purpose
 http://pablofierro.github.io/react-drag-select/

Answer (score 0):

check the article [React DnD Intro for the Redux developer](https://medium.com/@adamrackis/react-dnd-intro-for-the-redux-developer-d447c2c1577b)
 for built in drag&drop functionality

or you can include some good library to do the task they are many that you can find check https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc or http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/